# Filtering across two ManyToMany fields

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I have a `User` model and an `Event` model. I have the following for both:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    organization_map = models.ManyToManyField(Organization)

class User(AuthUser):
    ...
    subscribed_orgs = models.ManyToManyField('Organization')
```

I want to find all events that were created in a certain timeframe and find the users who are subscribed to those organizations. I know how to write SQL for this (it's very easy), but whats the pythonic way of doing this using Django ORM?

I'm trying as per below:

```
orgs = Organization.objects.all()
events = Event.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=min_time) # Min time is the time I want to start from
events = events.filter(organization_map__in=orgs)
```

But from there, how do I map to users who have that `organization` as a subscription?

I'm trying to map it like so:

```
users = User.objects.filter(subscribed_orgs__in=...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django can join across multiple tables at once, so you should be able to do the `users` query in one step:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=min_time)
users = User.objects.filter(subscribed_orgs__event__in=events).distinct()
```

(`distinct()` is necessary since a user could match in multiple ways.)

Since you know the SQL you're looking for, you can always check the SQL generated by Django to see if it matches your intuition. Check out the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) or use [`connection.queries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) directly.

Comment: `subscribed_orgs__event__in=events` -- doesn't that assume that `subscribed_orgs` which maps to `Organization` has a property events? If I understand it correctly...

Comment: Because `Event` maps to `Organization` and `User` also maps to `Organization`. They can be mapped to multiple `Organization`s.

Comment: @KVISH: `event` here is the reverse relationship from `Organization` to `Event`. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships): "To refer to a 'reverse' relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model."

Comment: So basically you're saying that if I have `Event` with ManyToManyField for `Organization`, it'll map automatically from `Organization`? Interesting.

Comment: @KVISH: Yes, that's right. In this case the query will return all users who've subscribed to any organization that is associated with any event in the `events` subquery. Django will take care of all the joins behind the scenes.